# How to create a login popup window similar to Windows 10 Sports App which is movable?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app

I tried to make a similar login pop up window using PopUp, MessageDialog and ContentDialog. But none of them satisfied my requirement. Please tell me how to achieve a similar popup window which has textbox and buttons in it using XAML or C# for building Windows Universal App.
Thank you in advance !

Pls see the box here. It is movable by mouse dragging also:
http://postimg.org/image/ucjm8hsk5/

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the dragging feature by using the *Manipulation* events and the *Projection* property.

I suggest you to use a **Border** that will contain all of your controls (in a **Grid** inside your **Border** for example) and set the *ManipulationMode* property to *All*.
Then attach a method to the *ManipulationDelta* event of your **Border** with the following code:

```
private void Border_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var border = (Border)sender;
    var currentProjection = border.Projection as PlaneProjection ?? new PlaneProjection();
    border.Projection = new PlaneProjection() { GlobalOffsetX = currentProjection.GlobalOffsetX + e.Delta.Translation.X, GlobalOffsetY =  currentProjection.GlobalOffsetY + e.Delta.Translation.Y };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! Actually I want a separate window to be opened when I click a button in UWP App.

Comment: You just need to bind a property of your ViewModel to the Visibility of the root control of your popup (the Border in my example).

Comment: I tried it but it has not worked out for me. Can we have a XAML Page opened in a new frame window when I click a button. Generally we have default window, but I want a new window opened without closing root window.